# Why deployed react app on gh-pages is showing blank page on different browsers while showing correctly on my browser?

Tags: reactjs, redux, github-pages

I have followed github pages deployment instructions and it's deployed correctly. But when I open the homepage link on another browser it's showing blank page.

my package.json file provided below

App link
https://abid413119.github.io/React-Redux-Todo-App/

```
{
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://abid413119.github.io/React-Redux-Todo-App",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it show correctly if you open it in your browser after making a build, not via dev-server? I think that there might be some issues with Store initialization where you supply the root reducer - check stack trace in the console

Comment: yes it's working after build but not working on different/ incognito browsers

Comment: Could you check the stack trace in console in incognito or different browser?

Comment: On console it is showing: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at redux.js:600
    at s (redux.js:79)
    at Module.303 (store.js:8)
    at p ((index):1)
    at Object.163 (main.67812e12.chunk.js:1)
    at p ((index):1)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Array.e [as push] ((index):1)
    at main.67812e12.chunk.js:1

Comment: It's solved. It was not working different browsers because of dev tools

Answer (score -1):

It is set to PRIVATE. Make it PUBLIC! Go to SETTINGS. At the bottom of the page there section Danger Zone. From there make it PUBLIC! And deploy your app all again!

Comment: You need to make it public and deploy it again.